# SQL query to turn change log into intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

So let me describe the problem:
-I have a task table with an assignee column, a created column and a resolved column 
(both created and resolved are timestamps)

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| task_id | assignee |  created   |  resolved  |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| tsk1    | him      | 2000-01-01 | 2018-01-03 |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

-I have a change log table with a task_id, a from column, a to column and a date column that records each time the assignee is changed

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| task_id | from     |  to        |  date      |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| tsk1    | me       | you        | 2017-04-06 |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| tsk1    | you      | him        | 2017-04-08 |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to select a table that shows a list of all the assignees that worked on a task within an interval

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| task_id | assignee |  from      |  to        |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| tsk1    | me       | 2000-01-01 | 2017-04-06 |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| tsk1    | you      | 2017-04-06 | 2017-04-08 |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+  
| tsk1    | him      | 2017-04-08 | 2018-01-03 |  
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I'm having trouble with the first(/last) row, where the from(/to) should be set as created(/resolved), I don't know how to make a column with data from two different tables...
I've tried making them in their own select and then merging all rows with union, but I don't think this is a very good solution...

Comment: That's the hill @jarlh will some day die on, flag in hand, while he is stampeded into the earth by all of us that use the terms interchangeably. Where's my coffee? OP, this feels like a good usecase for the [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) type in postgres with the [*/intersection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html) operator. It would make quick work of this, but you have to wrap your head around the whole concept first.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This is tricker than it seems.  The idea is to use `lead()` to get the next date, but you need to "augment" the data with information from the `tasks` table:

```
select task_id, to, date as fromdate,
       coalesce(lead(date) over (partition by task_id order by date),
                max(resolved) over (partition by task_id)
               ) as todate
from ((select task_id, to, date, null::timestamp
       from log l
      ) union all
      (select distint on (t.task_id) t.task_id, l.from, t.created, t.resolved
       from task t join
            log l
            on t.task_id = l.task_id
       order by t.task_id, l.date
      )
     ) t;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you put a union all instead of a simple union?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make it work using your code, I just had to add  `order by created` into the first `partition by task_id`

Comment: `union all` is preferable.  `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bf61f97c5e12d5df301ed8503f5f10a3)

```
SELECT 
    l.task_id, 
    assignee_from as assignee, 
    COALESCE(
         lag(assign_date) OVER (ORDER BY assign_date), 
         created
    ) as date_from,
    assign_date as date_to
FROM 
    log l 
JOIN
    task t
ON l.task_id = t.task_id

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (l.task_id)
        l.task_id, assignee_to, assign_date, resolved
    FROM 
        log l 
    JOIN
        task t
    ON l.task_id = t.task_id
    ORDER BY l.task_id, assign_date DESC
) s

ORDER BY task_id, date_from
```

`UNION` consists of two parts: The part from the log and finally the last row from the task table.

The first part uses [`LAG()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to get the previous date to the current row. Because `"me"` has no previous row, that would result in a `NULL` value. So this is catched by getting the `created` date from the `task` table.

The second part is to get the last row: Here I am getting the last row of the log by `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY assign_date DESC`. So I know the last `assignee_to`. The rest is similar to the first part: Getting the `resolved` value from the task table.

Comment: Why are you using MIN(created) in coalesce instead of just created? and why are you making a "select * (select distinct ...) s" instead of just "(select distinct ... ) s"

Comment: Good question, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from  S-Man and Gordon Linoff, I was able to come up with this solution:

```
SELECT t.task_id,
t.item_from AS assignee,
COALESCE(lag(t.changelog_created) OVER (
  PARTITION BY t.task_id ORDER BY t.changelog_created), 
  max(t.creationdate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.task_id)) AS fromdate,
t.changelog_created as todate
FROM ( SELECT ch.task_id,
        ch.item_from,
        ch.changelog_created,
        NULL::timestamp without time zone AS creationdate
       FROM changelog_generic_expanded_view ch
       WHERE ch.field::text = 'assignee'::text
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (t_1.id_task) t_1.id_task,
        t_1.assigneekey,
        t_1.resolutiondate,
        t_1.creationdate
       FROM task_jira t_1
      ORDER BY t_1.id_task)) t;
```

Note: this is the final version so the names are a bit different, but the idea stays the same.

This is basically the same code as Gordon Linoff, but I go through changelog in the opposite direction.
I use the 2nd part of UNION ALL to generate the last assignee instead of the first   (this is to handle the case where there is no changelog at all, the last assignee is generated without involving changelogs)